Relative Clause Modifying the Subject or the Object?
In a definition sentence like "React is a JavaScript library that lets you create single-page web applications," does the relative clause " that lets you create single-page web applications" modify "React" or "JavaScript library
The rule of proximity says the JavaScript library is being modified, also according to some grammar books, the JavaScript library again due to the fact "which type of library is meant? -> That lets you...".
However, the definition (context) says React.
This is not the only sentence of which I want to know the subject. But sentences like this one create confusion for me.

Semantically, I don't see how it makes any difference. But in something like John is a man who likes pizza, I think most people would say who likes pizza modifies John, not a man. If only because it's effectively just circumlocution for John likes pizza.

...also bear in mind that "React is a JavaScript library that lets you create single-page web applications" could in principle be used even if in fact no other JavaScript libraries let you do this. I don't know or care whether that's true in the real world; I'm just making a point about the verbal construction here.

Because "React is (a JavaScript library that lets you create single-page web applications),"  everything inside the parens applies to React. But that's true only because the dependent clause belongs to JS, not because it modifies React directly.

The relative clause modifies the nominal "Javascript library".


React is a JavaScript library that lets you create single-page web applications

In English, a relative clause goes after the noun that it modifies. So the relative clause here modifies "library" (or, in other terms, it is a modifier within the noun phrase that starts with "a JavaScript library").
Many sentences with a copula (or "linking verb") can be written in either order. You could rewrite this sentence to change which noun phrase is the subject, and the relative clause stays after "library":

A JavaScript library that lets you create single-page web applications is React.

(Or, perhaps more naturally, "One JavaScript library that... is React".)
As you note, this is a definition sentence. Semantically, the relative clause, the category "JavaScript library", and the name "React" all help describe the same thing.

I wouldn't quite go along with what you say. Integrated (defining) relatives modify nominals, not noun phrases. In the OP's example, the relative clause modifies the nominal "Javascript library".

Here, the relative clause is modifying
JavaScript library.
it means JavaScript Library -  let you create single-page web applications.
if you want to convey that React- let you create single-page web applications,
you have to put the relative clause after React.
But, linking verb is connects complement (JavaScript Library) with subject ( React). So, both represents the subject and complement as unique. So, it seems confusing.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can rewrite it as-
React that lets you create single-page web applications is a JavaScript library.
Now, the relative clause is modifying React. It means the single page web application feature is provided in React.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
